# Getting blank page when error in Laravel Valet WSL

Tags: laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, valet

I'm getting a blank page when an error occurs while using Valet WSL.

I can read the error on the "title" of the browser tab but it shows no page content.

I'm on Laravel 7 and valet-wsl 1.0.6 and WSL 1.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following

1. `.env` file is present in the project root with proper values
2. Check whether proper permissions are set on files and folders especially `bootstrap\cache` and `storage`
3. Whether the web-server user has the appropriate permissions on `bootstrap\cache` and `storage`

To set proper permissions on all files and folders in the project

```sh
# replace /var/www/myproject with path to your project on webserver root

find /var/www/myproject -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/myproject -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To ensure proper permissions on `bootstrap\cache` and storage`

```sh
# replace <non-root-sudo-user> with your username

setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwx,u:<non-root-sudo-user>:rwx storage
setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwx,u:<non-root-sudo-user>:rwx bootstrap/cache
setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwx,u:<non-root-sudo-user>:rwx storage
setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwx,u:<non-root-sudo-user>:rwx bootstrap/cache
```

These are the common pitfalls for getting a blank page